# falling flatforward curve in quantlib

Tags: interest-rates, quantlib, floating-rate

I am trying to create a floating rate bond where I need to create a flatforward curve, but the curve seems falling over the time, or is there any way to keep the rate constant.

```
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today
issueDate = ql.Date(11,10,2019)
maturityDate = ql.Date(11, 10, 2021)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Quarterly)
dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
bussinessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Forward
monthEnd = False
calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
faceValue = 100000
schedule = ql.Schedule(issueDate, maturityDate,tenor, calendar, ql.Unadjusted, ql.Unadjusted, dateGeneration,False)

forcast_curve = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
curve = ql.FlatForward(0,calendar,0.04, ql.Actual365Fixed(),ql.Simple)
#curve = ql.FlatForward(today,ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.04)),dayCount,ql.Simple,ql.Monthly)
forcast_curve.linkTo(curve)
index = ql.IborIndex("myindex",tenor, 0, ql.INRCurrency(),  calendar, ql.Unadjusted,  False, dayCount, forcast_curve)


nominals = faceValue
cashflows = ql.IborLeg(nominals=[nominals], schedule=schedule, index=index,paymentDayCounter=dayCount, paymentConvention =ql.ModifiedFollowing,fixingDays=[], gearings=[],spreads=[],caps=[])
bond = ql.Bond(0, calendar, 100.0,maturityDate, issueDate, cashflows)
yldcurve= ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(yldcurve)
bond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)
print([ql.as_coupon(c).rate() for c in bond.cashflows()])
```

output : [0.039999999999999584, 0.03960073776717019, 0.03921357971637247, 0.03883391850196816, 0.03845748603940633, 0.03808828133152389, 0.03773389848030649, 0.03738222040147477]

Answer (score 1):

Set the interest rate in the FlatForward construction to be ql.Compounded or ql.Continuous.

```
curve = ql.FlatForward(0,calendar,0.04, ql.Actual365Fixed(),ql.Compounded)
```

returns:
[0.03941521701609075, 0.03941309594147902, 0.03941309594147813, 0.03941521701609075, 0.03941521701609075, 0.0394109750189309, 0.03941309594147813, 0.03941521701609163]

Comment: if you also add the compounding frequency and set it to the one corresponding to your index tenor (quarterly, in this case), as in: `curve = ql.FlatForward(0,calendar,0.04, ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Compounded, tenor.frequency())` you get matching rates `[0.040001638428100776, 0.03999945387716691, 0.0399994538771678, 0.040001638428099895, 0.040001638428099895, 0.039997269485168845, 0.0399994538771678, 0.040001638428099895]`